# Regex remove certain characters from a file

Tags: python, regex, character

I'd like to write a python script that reads a text file containing this:

```
FRAME
  1  J=1,8  SEC=CL1  NSEG=2  ANG=0
  2  J=8,15  SEC=CL2  NSEG=2  ANG=0
  3  J=15,22  SEC=CL3  NSEG=2  ANG=0
```

And output a text file that looks like this:

```
1 1 8
2 8 15
3 15 22
```

I essentially don't need the commas or the SEC, NSEG and ANG data. Could someone help me use regex to do this?

So far I have this:

```
import re


r = re.compile(r"\s*(\d+)\s+J=(\S+)\s+SEC=(\S+)\s+NSEG=(\S+)+ANG=(\S+)\s")

with open('RawDataFile_445.txt') as a:

# open all 4 files with a meaningful name
file=[open(outputfile.txt","w") 
for line in a:
```

Comment: Play around with patterns at https://regex101.com/ or another Python flavored online regex tester (which there are many) until you get a pattern that works

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: You can do it without regular expressions, read each line; split the line on spaces and take the first two items, split the second item on `'='`; take the second item from that split and split on `','`.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Is there something that you are having trouble with specifically after reading the python regex documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without regex:

```
for line in file:
    keep = []
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith('FRAME'):
        continue
    first, second, *_ = line.split()
    keep.append(first)
    first, second = second.split('=')
    keep.extend(second.split(','))
    print(' '.join(keep))
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice? Since I don't write many regex's I avoid writing big ones all at once. Since you've already done that I would try to verify it a small chunk at a time, as illustrated in this code.

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"\s*(\d+)\s+J=(\S+)\s+SEC=(\S+)\s+NSEG=(\S+)+ANG=(\S+)\s")
r = re.compile(r"\s*(\d+)")
r = re.compile(r"\s*(\d+)\s+J=(\d+)")

with open('RawDataFile_445.txt') as a:
    a.readline()
    for line in a.readlines():
        result = r.match(line)
        if result:
            print (result.groups())
```

The first regex is your entire brute of an expression. The next line is the first chunk I verified. The next line is the second, bigger chunk that worked. Notice the slight change.

At this point I would go back, make the correction to the original, whole regex and then copy a bigger chunk to try. And re-run.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on an example string we want to parse:

```
  1  J=1,8
```

We have space(s), digit(s), more space(s), some characters, then digit(s), a comma, and more digit(s). If we replace them with regex characters, we get `(\d+)\s+J=(\d+),(\d+)`, where `+` means we want 1 or more of that type. Note that we surround the digits with parentheses so we can capture them later with `.groups()` or `.group(#)`, where # is the nth group.

Comment: So would you suggest using r = re.sub((\d+)\s+J=(\d+),(\d+))

Comment: @user7269405 No, we'd use `r = re.search(...)` to get the values we want, which we can grab using `r.groups()` or `r.group(#)`. Or use `re.findall()`. We're not trying to remove the characters we don't want; we're trying to only get the characters we do want.